# How can I install Ubuntu Server on a pre-configured RAID configuration?

Tags: installation, server, raid, ibm

I recently came into possession of an IBM xseries 346 server with 4 SCSI drives in some RAID configuration.  The server doesn't boot so I thought I would install Ubuntu server (12.04) on it, but when I go through the installation it doesn't find the disks.  I'm assumming this is is because the drives are handled by the ServeRAID-7k card.

I've tried putting Ubuntu drivers for the ServeRAID-7k on a USB to access while installing, but it didn't detect the USB drive so I'm kind of lost.

How can I install Ubuntu Server on this x346?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the IBM software (for a bootable CD) to update controller BIOS and configure RAID all-in-one bootable CD.
[IBM Support Download page for software.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=http://www.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-60624&ei=VTERUq3fKImayAH2pYEw&usg=AFQjCNGlTYSFmEekeexYtbg25ak8M1duTQ&sig2=u3ESn3qpH9XIA20UnwYu4A)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late reply but I myself have just got it to work with Ubuntu server 16.04,.

The link to the Firmware upgrade CD is correct, but not only does the CD update the firmware, it also is a CD accessed RAID configure GUI.

when the CD boots up (after enabling it to be first boot device) it will open to the grey screen with an X in the center (the X is the mouse), after roughly 1 minute it will show you a screen that will tell you if your firmware is up to date or needs to be upgraded, if it needs to be upgraded then go ahead, if not just start checking the menus in the top right corner and you should find something about the RAID in there. i'm not in front of the server right now otherwise I could give a more accurate description of where to go.

Once you activate the drive in RAID it will then be visible to Ubuntu and you can install Ubuntu onto that server.

I hope this helps whoever is trying to do the same thing.